# How to do conditional rendering in react with combining components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to do concatenation just like we do in string in js in react components and want to deliver them like below

```
<Fragment>

              {score_array.map((ScoreArray, idx) => {
                let _re;
                   if(!ScoreArray.score_childs)
                   {

                    _re+=
                      <Colxx key={idx} sm={6}>

                       <Input
                         type="number"
                         pattern="[0-9]*"
                         inputMode="numeric"
                         className="number_type"
                         placeholder={ScoreArray.score_name}
                         name="score_value"
                         value={ScoreArray.score_value}
                         onChange={this.handleScoreArrayValueChange(idx)}
                       />
                     </Colxx>

                   }

                   else{

                    ScoreArray.score_childs.map((_scorechild,id)=>{
                      _re+=
                        <Colxx key={idx} sm={6}>

                         <Input
                           type="number"
                           pattern="[0-9]*"
                           inputMode="numeric"
                           className="number_type"
                           placeholder={_scorechild.score_name}
                           name="score_value"
                           value={ScoreArray.score_value}
                           onChange={this.handleScoreArrayValueChange(idx)}
                         />
                       </Colxx>




                    })

                   }

               return _re;


              })}
            </Fragment>
```

The array is something like which I am trying to iterate

```
let score_array= [
     {
      "score_name": "GMAT",
        "ps_score_id": 200,
        "score_childs":null
      },
      {
        "score_name": "GRE",
        "ps_score_id": 2,
        "score_childs": [
          {
            "score_name": "GRE READ",
            "ps_score_id": 9
          },
          {
            "score_name": "GRE WRITE",
            "ps_score_id": 10
          },
          {
            "score_name": "GRE SPEAK",
            "ps_score_id": 11
          },
          {
            "score_name": "GRE LISTEN",
            "ps_score_id": 12
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

I want a structure like

```
<h1>GMAT</h1>
<input  name="GMAT ">

<h1>GRE</h1>
<input  name="GRE READ ">
<input  name="GRE WRITE ">
<input  name="GRE SPEAK ">
```

Currently its displaying [object] [object] in the dom ,I want a structure as mentioned above ,Any help will be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Can you create a stackblits working demo

Comment: Kindly check the official document [conditional-rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Comment: Yeah but how to join them .

Comment: Just take a think: when you perform `_re+= <Colxx key={idx} sm={6}>...` you are trying to get a sum of `undefined` and `Object` which is completely senseless and properly returns you `"[object]"` string instead. Result of every `map` callback call must be a single Object.

Comment: Yeah that ' what I am asking how to get the elements back

Comment: Refer to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/granmoe/274c299b792b039deecfb619753ea32c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to concat components like string, you can just render the array using map directly like this:

```
<Fragment>
    // for each item
    {score_array.map((ScoreArray, idx) => {
      // if it doesn't have children render it directly
      if (!ScoreArray.score_childs) {
        return <Colxx key={idx} sm={6}>
          <Input
            type="number"
            pattern="[0-9]*"
            inputMode="numeric"
            className="number_type"
            placeholder={ScoreArray.score_name}
            name="score_value"
            value={ScoreArray.score_value}
            onChange={this.handleScoreArrayValueChange(idx)}
          />
        </Colxx>;
      } else {
        // if it has children render all of them one by one
        return ScoreArray.score_childs.map((_scorechild, id) => (
          <Colxx key={id} sm={6}>
            <Input
              type="number"
              pattern="[0-9]*"
              inputMode="numeric"
              className="number_type"
              placeholder={_scorechild.score_name}
              name="score_value"
              value={ScoreArray.score_value}
              onChange={this.handleScoreArrayValueChange(idx)}
            />
          </Colxx>
        ));
      }
    })}
</Fragment>
```

Here's a shorter way which also adds an h1 tag and replaces the if statement with a ternary operator:

```
    <Fragment>
      {score_array.map((ScoreArray, idx) => (
        <Fragment>
          <h1>{ScoreArray.score_name}</h1>
          {!ScoreArray.score_childs ? (
            <Colxx key={idx} sm={6}>
              <Input
                type="number"
                pattern="[0-9]*"
                inputMode="numeric"
                className="number_type"
                placeholder={ScoreArray.score_name}
                name="score_value"
                value={ScoreArray.score_value}
                onChange={this.handleScoreArrayValueChange(idx)}
              />
            </Colxx>
          ) : ScoreArray.score_childs.map((_scorechild, id) => (
            <Colxx key={id} sm={6}>
              <Input
                type="number"
                pattern="[0-9]*"
                inputMode="numeric"
                className="number_type"
                placeholder={_scorechild.score_name}
                name="score_value"
                value={ScoreArray.score_value}
                onChange={this.handleScoreArrayValueChange(idx)}
              />
            </Colxx>
          ))}
        </Fragment>
      ))}
    </Fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firs thing you can not use if... Else statment in JSX

- Make one separate method and return input controll based on condition and use in reder method